# How do I declare a vector type in the proper way?

Tags: c++, vector, compiler-errors

Why do I get the following error in my header file:

> error: 'MyTreeModelNodePtrArray' does not name a type; did you mean
> 'MyTreeModelNode'?

The header code is:

```
#ifndef MYTREEMODELNODE_H 
#define MYTREEMODELNODE_H

#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class MyTreeModelNode;
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyTreeModelNode>> MyTreeModelNodePtrArray;

class MyTreeModelNode final
{
public:

    MyTreeModelNode(MyTreeModelNode* parent, int id, const wxString& column1, const wxString& column2, const wxString& column3, const wxString& column4);
    MyTreeModelNode(MyTreeModelNode* parent, const wxString& branch);
    ~MyTreeModelNode();

    MyTreeModelNode* GetParent();
    MyTreeModelNodePtrArray& GetChildren();    //here the error

private:
    MyTreeModelNode* pParent;
    MyTreeModelNodePtrArray mChildren;
};

#endif // MYTREEMODELNODE_H
```

Comment: You've declared `MyTreeModelNodePtrArray` as a variable when you write `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyTreeModelNode>> MyTreeModelNodePtrArray;`.  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: TLDR you should not, global variables are just bad design. Global variables tend to glue pieces of software together in an implicit kind of way making maintenance and unit testability suffer. You might want to watch [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QthAU-t3PQ4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QthAU-t3PQ4)

Comment: @PepijnKramer I'm assuming they don't really want that global variable and just want to define the type alias. This assumption certainly fits with the subsequent class member definitions.

Comment: @AdrianMole Fair point. I missed that, because of the actual global in the code. Even then I would say a type alias might still be semantically weak and it is an option to wrap that vector in a class of its own.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is in this line:

```cpp
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyTreeModelNode>> MyTreeModelNodePtrArray;
```

This declares `MyTreeModelNodePtrArray` as a global **variable** of type `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyTreeModelNode>>`, whose identifier (name) cannot then (later) be used as a type of variable.

What you actually appear to want is to define `MyTreeModelNodePtrArray` as an *alias* for a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyTreeModelNode>>`. This can be done with the `using` keyword:

```cpp
class MyTreeModelNode;
// Create the "MyTreeModelNodePtrArray" type alias...
using MyTreeModelNodePtrArray = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyTreeModelNode>>;

class MyTreeModelNode final
{
public:

    MyTreeModelNode(MyTreeModelNode* parent, int id, const wxString& column1, const wxString& column2, const wxString& column3, const wxString& column4);
    MyTreeModelNode(MyTreeModelNode* parent, const wxString& branch);
    ~MyTreeModelNode();

    MyTreeModelNode* GetParent();
    MyTreeModelNodePtrArray& GetChildren(); // Now no error

private:
    MyTreeModelNode* pParent;
    MyTreeModelNodePtrArray mChildren;      // Or here
};
```

[Further reading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias).

Comment: Love it! I guess that was easy for you guys! Thanks a lot!

Comment: One definition of "easy" is, "something you know how to do." One definition for "difficult" is, "something you don't know how to do." These are reasons why Q/A sites like Stack Overflow exist.